# Using qgis model designer instead of writing a plugin

Tags: plugins, qgis, pyqgis

I have been tasked to develop a plugin for Qgis for some of my coworkers to use when handlede GIS data.
In that process I found the Qgis model designer and are using that to build my workflow and then export that to a python script.

My question is, why not simnply send the model to my coworkers? why is there a need for plugins when it seems to me that the models can du the same?

Comment: A model requires a user to be familiar with the model builder. A plugin doesn't. A plugin hides the details from the user.

To my knowledge, the user has to edit the model to modify the input parameters whereas a plugin may provide a dialog allowing the user to enter input parameters. 

In addition, IMHO, a plugin also discourages others from changing the behaviour of the plugin, in a model this may be easily (maybe even unintentionally) done. Having derivated versions of a model will make troubleshooting way more difficult when an issue occurs.